parse the json into string in Javascript
I need to generate certain format of data according to some rules, the sample data is as showed below
 "biz_content": "{\"create_ip\":\"127.0.0.1\",\"create_time\":\"20231114110200\",\"expire_time\":\"20231124110200\"

so i thought it would be ok to parse the json data directly into string by using
   biz_content: 
   {
    "create_ip":"127.0.0.1",
    "create_time":"20240523093226",
    "expire_time":"20240523095226",
    ...
   }
   JSON.stringify( json )

but the resulted string is like
"biz_content": '{"create_ip":"127.0.0.1","create_time":"20240523093226","expire_time":"20240523095226",...}'

how would I parse it to the format like
  "{\"create_ip\":\"127.0.0.1\",\"create_time\"


What do you mean by a format like "{\"create_ip\":\"127.0.0.1\",\"create_time\"? You mean, textual format with quotes, instead of a javascript object?

yes, a string parsed from Json format, and this string is printed out with \

biz_content is a string that also needs to be JSON.stringify'd. ' is not a legal bare character in JSON, so the contents are currently a string containing the object contents.

You need to stringify the nested object as well:


const json = JSON.stringify({
  biz_content: JSON.stringify({
    create_ip: "127.0.0.1",
    create_time: "20240523093226",
    expire_time: "20240523095226",
  })
});

console.log(json);



You can strip off the curly braces if that's required by your format:
json = json.slice(1, -1))

